# Creating a reusable animation using AOT compilation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular-animations

I'm trying to create a reusable animation but I'm getting the following error when compiling my app with [angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli):

`Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'flyInOut', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function`

It only happens when using AOT compilation, though. If I set the `aot` flag to `false`, then it works.

Here's my function:

```
export function flyInOut(enter: string, leave: string, duration?: number): AnimationMetadata {
  const timing: number = duration || 100;
  return trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({ transform: `translateX(${enter})` }),
      animate(timing),
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(timing, style({ transform: `translateX(${leave})` })),
    ]),
  ]);
}
```

Any ideas on how to make it work with AOT compilation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a known issue tracked in the [official repo](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15587). This issue occurs when using variables inside our function. A workaround is obtaining that result from another exported function:

```
export function flyInOut(enter: string, leave: string, duration?: number): AnimationMetadata {
  return trigger('flyInOut', [
    state('in', style({ transform: 'translateX(0)' })),
    transition('void => *', [
      style({ transform: getTranslate(enter) }),
      animate(getDuration(duration)),
    ]),
    transition('* => void', [
      animate(100, style({ transform: getTranslate(leave) })),
    ]),
  ]);
}
```

In the example above, we call `getTranslate` and `getDuration` instead of using the `duration`, `enter` and `leave` variables. Then, we export those functions returning the proper value:

```
export function getDuration(duration: number): number {
  return duration || 100;
}

export function getTranslate(value: string): string {
  return `translateX(${value}%)`;
}
```